# Victim loses Internet connection during MITM attack

Tags: attacks, wifi, man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing

I tried to do MITM attack on my network. I enabled `ettercap`, marked my router as TARGET1 and my second computer as TARGET2. Then I enabled 'ARP Spoofing'.
I do not know why - but after this operation my victim has lost Internet connection. I do not see anything in `urlsnarf`. It seems the both sides of my plan get known there are some troubles - below I post results from Wireshark capturing.

My question is? What do I do wrong? What should I improve to make good MITM attack. To this attack I used external Wi-Fi card, I have also one more, built-in, interface (it was connected to same network). I have enabled ipv4 forwarding (`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` == 1).

Results of Wireshark capturing:

```
   No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      9 0.582284000    Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 9: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     10 0.582393000    Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 10: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 9)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 9)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    118 10.582643000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 118: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    119 10.582701000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 119: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 118)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 118)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    140 20.582933000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 140: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    141 20.582995000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 141: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 140)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 140)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    171 30.583194000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 171: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    172 30.583261000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 172: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 171)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 171)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    185 40.583479000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 185: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    186 40.583543000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 186: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 185)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 185)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    330 50.583765000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 330: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    331 50.583831000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 331: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 330)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 330)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    333 51.601767000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.101

Frame 333: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (request)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    334 51.602934000   Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ROUTER MAC]

Frame 334: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1728 60.584062000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 1728: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1729 60.584131000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 1729: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 1728)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 1728)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1849 70.584400000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 1849: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1850 70.584480000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 1850: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 1849)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 1849)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1896 80.584691000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 1896: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1897 80.584765000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 1897: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 1896)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 1896)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1932 90.584985000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 1932: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1933 90.585049000   Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 1933: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 1932)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 1932)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1946 100.585252000  Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 1946: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1947 100.585312000  Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 1947: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 1946)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 1946)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1992 110.585539000  Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 1992: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1993 110.585597000  Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 1993: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 1992)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 1992)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2054 120.585783000  Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     192.168.0.100 is at [ATTACKER MAC]

Frame 2054: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2055 120.585833000  Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     AsustekC_a7:27:9a     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ATTACKER MAC] (duplicate use of 192.168.0.100 detected!)

Frame 2055: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: AsustekC_a7:27:9a ([VICTIM MAC])
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.1 ([ATTACKER MAC]) - also in use by [ROUTER MAC] (frame 2054)]
[Duplicate IP address detected for 192.168.0.100 ([VICTIM MAC]) - also in use by [ATTACKER MAC] (frame 2054)]
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2061 124.609742000  Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     ARP      42     Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.101

Frame 2061: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (request)

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   2062 124.610917000  Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50     Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30     ARP      42     192.168.0.1 is at [ROUTER MAC]

Frame 2062: 42 bytes on wire (336 bits), 42 bytes captured (336 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Tp-LinkT_8c:13:50 ([ROUTER MAC]), Dst: Tp-LinkT_21:e9:30 ([ATTACKER MAC])
Address Resolution Protocol (reply)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, but we'll need more information anyway. What's the ouput of 'iptables -L'? What command are you using to launch the attack? What's the content of the victim's arp-tables after you run the attack (windows: 'arp -a' , linux: 'arp')?

Comment: @Michael "ARP Positions" -> "Sniff ....." -> Start

Comment: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: And the output of the arp command on the victim machine? By the way, I suggest looking into the commandline version of ettercap, to really understand what is happening. Please mention that command here as well.

Answer (score 3):

You probably aren't routing their traffic to the gateway.

You told the victim that you're the gateway and you told the gateway you're the victim, but when the victim tries sending you traffic you haven't configured your computer to forward their traffic to the gateway.

You can accomplish this with iptables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that traffic flows through your machine. For the gateway and the computer YOU are, respectively, the computer or the gateway. Your probably blocking all the traffic now to that of so that's why the computer is losing his Internet connection. Not his LAN.

Fix this in your firewall, proxy. On Linux iptables will do the job. A simple Google search will give you the right configuration.